# Distance of a point from a line using multiplicative distance

Tags: geometry

How can we determine the multiplicative distance (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10115-014-0813-4#page-1) of a point (x0,y0) from a line  (ax+by+c=0)?

Let X = (x_1, x_2 ..., x_m) be a random vector with x_k ∼ F_k , k = 1,...,m and Q = (q_1, q_2,..., q_m) be a query point with q_k ∼ F˜_k .                              Set z_k = 1 + |x_k − q_k|. The general form of the multiplicative distance of X from Q is defined as:
MD(X,Q)=(z_1^c_1)*(z_2^c_2)*....(z_m^c_m) - 1
where c_k > 0 is named “control power,” which controls the effect of each z_k on the distance. z_k is defined as the distance component. If ∀k : c_k = c, each dimension has the equal effect on the distance.
Note that the multiplicative distance is not a metric. In other words, how distance of a point from a line can be found by a distance that forms a non metric space?

Comment: What distance measure did you have in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by "line" under this definition? Do you mean "geodesic under the Euclidean metric"?

Comment: What metric space to you have in mind?

Comment: It sounds like you should be asking this on math.SE instead of here…

Comment: The site won't show (me) page 1. Can you include the definition in the question?  It is generally the policy that questions be self-contained whenever possible.

Comment: I don't understand the reopen votes. The cited paper is behind a paywall and the question is unanswerable without it.

Comment: Let X = (x1, x2 ..., xm) be a random vector with xk ∼ Fk , k = 1,..., m and
Q = (q1, q2,..., qm) be a query point with qk ∼ F˜k .                              Set zk = 1 + |xk − qk|. The general
form of the multiplicative distance of X from Q is defined as:
MD(X,Q)=(z1^c1)*(z2^c2)*....(zm^cm) - 1
where ck > 0 is named “control power,” which controls the effect of each zk on the distance.
z
ck
k is defined as the distance component. If ∀k : ck = c, each dimension has the equal effect
on the distance. I

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it (not what @Patrick suggested)

```
line[t_] := {ax, ay} + {bx, by} t
pt = {px, py};
ax = ay = bx = by = 2
px = 77; py = 142;

Minimize[ChessboardDistance[pt, line@t], t]
(* {65/2, {t -> 215/4}} *)
```